# Android parcelable class which uses a handler

Tags: android, handler

I have a class which can execute a number of threads.

to deal with the threads I pass the class a reference to a handler (from the main activity) the threads then send messages to this handler as and when they need to.

My problem is that I want to make this class parcelable so that all the data it holds does not need to be reloaded when the phone orientation is changed. What can I do about the handler reference which is passed in when the object is first created?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you looked into a messenger (parcelable container for a handler)? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html